# Excel - How to do the following?

Tags: excel, vba, interpolation, price

I have a question related to EXCEL:

Since I have the following prices for different period, how can I compute in an automatic way, for example the price between 10 June - 15 July ?

[image]

EDIT--> Expected output:
50€+50€ (10-11 june)  + 58€x13 (period 12 june - 25 June) + 75€x13 (period 26 june - 9 July) + 92€x5 (period 10 july-15july) = 2289€

This is the same pictures with the cells in excel, please do not consider the "Price of period", but only the daily price

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question, and add the expected output. With current info it will be hard to know if the price is `50+50+350+450+92+92+92+92+92+92`=1452 or if the price is `50+50+350+450+550`=1450

Comment: @Luuk  you are right, now is done! :)

Comment: Please show what you have tried.  It is difficult to tell from your screenshot what cells the data is in.  Please clarify. Also, why are you not counting all the days in the 2nd, 3rd and 4th periods, but you are in the first period.  What is the relation between the `Price of Period` and the `Daily Price`?

Comment: "58€x13 (period 12 june - 25 June)" But from 12 jun - 25 jun is (12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25)= 14 days ?

Comment: @Luuk That is one of my questions. In your expected output, you seem to be only counting one fewer than the actual number of days except for the first group.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: sorry, missed that.... 

Comment: I suggest you create an array of the relevant dates, and then use sumproduct to multiply each by the relevant daily price.  Assuming the data in what appears to be merged cells is actually in the upper left corner, and the dates are "real dates" and not just strings, you can do this with `INDIRECT` or, if you have it `SEQUENCE`.  (Or VBA or Power Query if you prefer). If they are not real dates, you will have to convert them first.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a (lengthy) calculation:

Consider:

1. A8 Contains the from date (10-06-2021)
2. B8 Contains the from date (17-07-2021)

```
=(MIN($B$8,D3)-MAX($A$8,C3)+1)*C5+(MIN($B$8,F3)-MAX($A$8,E3)+1)*E5+(MIN($B$8,H3)-MAX($A$8,G3)+1)*G5+(MIN($B$8,J3)-MAX($A$8,I3)+1)*I5
```

This will consider a period from `10-06` - `11-06` a period of 2 days. And also `12-06` - `25-06` a period of 14 days, and so on.

The result is: `2514.00`

Comment: Can you link your xlsx file please? I am not able to do it..

Comment: In cell `A8`, you type `10-06-2021`, in cell `B8` you type `17-07-2021`, and (i.e.) in cell `C8`, you copy and paste the formula that i gave.... That should not be very difficult?

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to create a lookup table and use a formula.

Given your data, your lookup table might as shown below:

I **NAME**'d it: `priceTable`

You can then use the formula:

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(End-Start+1,,Start,1),priceTable,2))
```

If, for some reason, you cannot easily create `priceTable`, you can create it with a formula (depending on your version of Excel):

```
=INDEX($C$4:$I$6,{1,3},{1;3;5;7})
```

**Note:** All of the formulas assume your dates are real dates and not strings.

[image]

If your version of Excel does not have the `SEQUENCE` function, you can replace it with:

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,Start):INDEX($A:$A,End)),priceTable,2))
```